# Sefira Nuschaos Differences

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, nuschaot

What are the differences between the various Nuschaos in Sefiras Haomer (e.g. Ashkenaz says this, Sefard says that...)?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7017/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To tie up everything that's been said (and more):

- Nusach Ashkenaz generally say BaOmer at the end
- Nusach Sefard generally say LaOmer at the end
- Nusach of Sefardim (i.e. Edut Mizrach) say LaOmer before the weeks
- Nusach of Teiman say the count like the Nusach of Sefardim, except they say it in Aramaic [and say baomer(?)]
- I have seen (and not confirmed) that Nusach of Italian say the word LaOmer directly after Hayom

For example, on the 22nd day of the Omer:

- Ashkenaz: הַיּוֹם שְׁנַיִם וְעֶשְׂרִים יוֹם שֶׁהֵם שְׁלֹשָׁה שָׁבוּעוֹת וְיוֹם אֶחָד בָּעֹמֶר
- Sefard: הַיּוֹם שְׁנַיִם וְעֶשְׂרִים יוֹם שֶׁהֵם שְׁלֹשָׁה שָׁבוּעוֹת וְיוֹם אֶחָד לָעֹמֶר
- Sefardi: הַיּוֹם שְׁנַיִם וְעֶשְׂרִים יוֹם לָעֹמֶר שֶׁהֵם שְׁלֹשָׁה שָׁבוּעוֹת וְיוֹם אֶחָד
- Teiman: הַאידַּאנָא עַשׂרִין וּתרֵין יוֹמֵי בְּעֻמרָא, דְּאִנּוּן תְּלָתָא שָׁבוּעֵי וְחַד יוֹמָא
- Italian: הַיּוֹם לָעֹמֶר שְׁנַיִם וְעֶשְׂרִים יוֹם שֶׁהֵם שְׁלֹשָׁה שָׁבוּעוֹת וְיוֹם אֶחָד

Also note: the Leshem Yichud also varies based on Nusach.

Comment: it varies even among Sefaradim because I believe there is Mahloket Rishonim whether Sefira nowadays is Deorayta or Derabanan. I believe Yalkut Yosef says not to say the Pasuk and the words "mitvat aseh deorayta" because he holds nowadays Derabanan.

Comment: @H'Gabriel Thanks for that info. I was focusing on the "day" part of the nusach, though.

Comment: Just wanted to bring that up

Comment: @yydl, Bnei Ashkenaz (Germans) say la'omer instead of ba'omer, however the placement is identical to other Ashkenazi siddurim.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Interesting. So I guess they follow Nusach Sefard with that respect?

Comment: @yydl, no, as Dave points out, R' Hamburger's research in the subject turns up only one major dissenting opinion on la'omer vs ba'omer: the Ta"z. http://treasuresofashkenaz.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/omer-laomer-baomer-shehayom-sefiras-haomer-debunked-and-demystified-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D/

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Ah. Yes. Okay.

Comment: I can confirm what you cite as Italian as correct in the Roman _nusach_, according to a Passover _machzor_ in what claims to be the Roman _nusach_ that I saw today.

Answer (score 4):

Nusach Sefard says La'Omer - Nusach Ashkenaz says Ba'Omer

Nusach Sefard says everything in the Siddur - Nusach Ashkenaz only the Beracha, day, and HaRachaman

Comment: Sefard meaning nusach sefard, or sefardim?

Comment: In truth it is both. Based on the Arizal.

Comment: @Yahu's answer- with the exception of the Ashkenaz Artscroll which is partial to the Mishnah Berurah over mesorah!!!

Comment: YDK you mean Gershon's answer which I edited.

Comment: Note the [old] Ashkenazi custom (eg. Tos Megillah 20b) is to say "Yehi Ratzon SheYibbaneh..." not "Harachaman". Saying "Harachaman" is a Sefardi thing.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other differences noted in the other answer, my understanding is that *S'faradim* say *laomer* before the weeks' count ("*shehem...*"), and *Ashk'nazim* after it. (No source, but check your nearby *S'faradi sidur*. (I don't have one nearby at the moment.))

Answer (score 3):

For a very nice synopsis of the history behind these versions, see [this piece](http://treasuresofashkenaz.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/omer-laomer-baomer-shehayom-sefiras-haomer-debunked-and-demystified-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D/) from R' Binyomin Shlomo Hamburger.