# Why don't we count sfeirah **m**'omer (from the omer)?

Tags: halacha-theory, grammar-dikduk, sefirat-ha-omer

There are [different nusachot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6508/sefira-nuschaos-differences/7157#7157) that count sfirah as "ba'omer" or "la'omer." But shouldn't we count days ***m***'omer? The omer was brought on the 16th and that's what we are counting from. Leviticus 23:15 says: וּסְפַרְתֶּם לָכֶם, מִמָּחֳרַת הַשַּׁבָּת, מִיּוֹם הֲבִיאֲכֶם, אֶת-עֹמֶר הַתְּנוּפָה:  שֶׁבַע שַׁבָּתוֹת, תְּמִימֹת תִּהְיֶינָה. So why are we counting days "in" the omer or "of" the omer instead of counting "from" the omer?

Perhaps the flip side of the question is what do "baomer" and "laomer" mean? The omer is a sheaf of grain, what does it mean to have days "in" or "of" the sheaf? The Torah does not call the days themselves "the Omer."

Comment: Right there in the blessing we say העומר

Comment: I don't see your point. The blessing comes much later than the Torah. Also "al sfirat haomer" doesn't necessarily mean you are counting something called the omer. It could mean the counting that relates to the omer. (Though presumably if you said "l'spor haomer" b'dieved you're yotzei). "Sfirat hazav" does not mean you are counting zavim.

Comment: "The blessing comes much later than the Torah." So does appending "laomer"/"baomer" to the count, so not sure why that matters

Comment: Because my question is on the svara that went into it. Why (and perhaps when) did the Torah's concept of counting *from* the omer become instead a concept of counting "the omer." Conversely, why do you assume "laomer" or "baomer" came later? What nusach do you think Moshe and David HaMelekh used?

Comment: Even most rishonim didn't say laomer. Someone asked the rashba if it made sense to add laomer to help be extra clear of the meaning, and he said why not doesn't hurt.

Comment: The Taz in siman 489 seems to indicate that Laomer means "from the Korban Omer" as if to say L'korban Omer (since the korban omer) and Baomer means "in the days of the omer" not referring to the korban at all. So your question would be only on the ones who say Laomer, to better say M'omer

Comment: "mei-omer" would be one day off. Day one of the omer is the day the qorban is brought, zero days after the omer.

Comment: @Avraham, Isn't the idea of sefira to count towards Shavuous? If your question is why are counting towards Shavuous, then that is spoken about by many commentaries on Chumash and the Chagim.

Comment: @JoeJam my question is on the phrasing of counting "the omer" and not "from the omer." I would not have a question if the nusach were "x days laShavuot"

Comment: @MichaBerger fair point but I think we see counting like that in other places, e.g., the brit is on the 8th day after birth, even though the birth isn't day 0. The pasuk explicitly says to count "from the day you bring the Omer"

Comment: @Chatzkel Thanks for that Taz. That's interesting. But I think my Q is also on those who say "baomer," because what are they "days of the omer"? We don't see in the time period that the time period itself is called the omer.

Comment: @Avraham, I believe the pasuq is saying that while we count every day starting "from" the day after Pesach's first full holiday (ממלכת השבת) the count itself isn't time since. Or else we would start with counting zero. The Maadanei Yom Tov even suggests that day zero was a day later that first year because it wasn't whole - the ge'ulah was at midnight and noon. And that is how the MYT explains how the זמן מתן תורתנו which is day 50 was on the 7th of Sivan that year, but the 6th of Sivan now that we start Pesach at sundown, making that day whole and a valid zero.

Comment: @Avraham, until around that Taz few Jews were saying either. Just היום תשע־עשרה יום שהם שני שבועות וחמישה ימים. Full stop. The only reason to expect biblical language is that we refer to Pesach as "Chag haMatzos."